# Concatenating fields in select clause JOOQ

Tags: mysql, jooq

I'm working in a query using JOOQ and I'm trying to output a column as a 
concatenation (space separated) of other fields extracted in the same query.

Getting into detail, with the next code I try to create a select statement with a column called fullAdress by grouping all the address lines contained in the address table. So, for each field, if it's not null or empty it will be concatenated to the result (actually no space is being added).

```
@Override
protected List<Field<?>> selectCustomFields() {
    List<Field<?>> customSelect = new ArrayList<Field<?>>();

    // Fields to use in the concatenation
    Field<?> field1 = field("addr.AddressLine1"),   field2 = field("addr.AddressLine2"),field3 = field("addr.AddressLine3"),
             field4 = field("addr.AddressLine4"),   field5 = field("addr.PostalCode"),  field6 = field("addr.City"),
             field7 = field("addr.State"),          field8 = field("addr.County"),      field9 = field("addr.Country");

    // Create non null/empty conditions
    Condition condLine1 = field1.isNotNull().and(field1.length().ne(0));
    Condition condLine2 = field2.isNotNull().and(field2.length().ne(0));
    Condition condLine3 = field3.isNotNull().and(field3.length().ne(0));
    Condition condLine4 = field4.isNotNull().and(field4.length().ne(0));
    Condition condLine5 = field5.isNotNull().and(field5.length().ne(0));
    Condition condLine6 = field6.isNotNull().and(field6.length().ne(0));
    Condition condLine7 = field7.isNotNull().and(field7.length().ne(0));
    Condition condLine8 = field8.isNotNull().and(field8.length().ne(0));
    Condition condLine9 = field9.isNotNull().and(field9.length().ne(0));

    // Concat address lines when meets condition
    customSelect.add(concat(DSL.when(condLine1, field1),
                            DSL.when(condLine2, field2),
                            DSL.when(condLine3, field3),
                            DSL.when(condLine4, field4),
                            DSL.when(condLine5, field5),
                            DSL.when(condLine6, field6),
                            DSL.when(condLine7, field7),
                            DSL.when(condLine8, field8),
                            DSL.when(condLine9, field9))
                            .as("fullAddress"));
    return customSelect;
}
```

JOOQ will generate the next from the previous select statement, which is giving a null value and not concatenating the fields correctly.

```
select 
  concat(
    cast(case when (
               addr.AddressLine1 is not null
               and char_length(cast(addr.AddressLine1 as char)) <> 0
             ) then addr.AddressLine1 end as char), 
    cast(case when (
               addr.AddressLine2 is not null
               and char_length(cast(addr.AddressLine2 as char)) <> 0
             ) then addr.AddressLine2 end as char), 
    cast(case when (
               addr.AddressLine3 is not null
               and char_length(cast(addr.AddressLine3 as char)) <> 0
             ) then addr.AddressLine3 end as char), 
    cast(case when (
               addr.AddressLine4 is not null
               and char_length(cast(addr.AddressLine4 as char)) <> 0
             ) then addr.AddressLine4 end as char), 
    cast(case when (
               addr.PostalCode is not null
               and char_length(cast(addr.PostalCode as char)) <> 0
             ) then addr.PostalCode end as char), 
    cast(case when (
               addr.City is not null
               and char_length(cast(addr.City as char)) <> 0
             ) then addr.City end as char), 
    cast(case when (
               addr.State is not null
               and char_length(cast(addr.State as char)) <> 0
             ) then addr.State end as char), 
    cast(case when (
               addr.County is not null
               and char_length(cast(addr.County as char)) <> 0
             ) then addr.County end as char), 
    cast(case when (
               addr.Country is not null
               and char_length(cast(addr.Country as char)) <> 0
             ) then addr.Country end as char)) as `fullAddress`
from Address as `addr`
  ....
```

My questions are,

- how should I create my select statement correctly?
- how can I best add the space separator?
- is there any better alternative to JOOQ ( when = case ) condition clause?

Comment: concatenation with custom separator: [Concat_ws](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### how should I create my select statement correctly?

You forgot the `CASE .. ELSE` part, or `otherwise()` in jOOQ:

```java
// Concat address lines when meets condition
customSelect.add(concat(DSL.when(condLine1, field1).otherwise(""),
                        DSL.when(condLine2, field2).otherwise(""),
                        DSL.when(condLine3, field3).otherwise(""),
                        DSL.when(condLine4, field4).otherwise(""),
                        DSL.when(condLine5, field5).otherwise(""),
                        DSL.when(condLine6, field6).otherwise(""),
                        DSL.when(condLine7, field7).otherwise(""),
                        DSL.when(condLine8, field8).otherwise(""),
                        DSL.when(condLine9, field9).otherwise(""))
                        .as("fullAddress"));
```

#### how can I best add the space separator?

If you want an additional space separator between your address parts, you could write:

```java
// Concat address lines when meets condition
customSelect.add(concat(DSL.when(condLine1, field1.concat(" ")).otherwise(""),
                        DSL.when(condLine2, field2.concat(" ")).otherwise(""),
                        DSL.when(condLine3, field3.concat(" ")).otherwise(""),
                        DSL.when(condLine4, field4.concat(" ")).otherwise(""),
                        DSL.when(condLine5, field5.concat(" ")).otherwise(""),
                        DSL.when(condLine6, field6.concat(" ")).otherwise(""),
                        DSL.when(condLine7, field7.concat(" ")).otherwise(""),
                        DSL.when(condLine8, field8.concat(" ")).otherwise(""),
                        DSL.when(condLine9, field9.concat(" ")).otherwise("")).trim()
                        .as("fullAddress"));
```

#### is there any better alternative to JOOQ ( when = case ) condition clause?

I think the approach is sound. Of course, you probably shouldn't repeat all that logic all the time, but create a loop of the sort:

```java
List<Field<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++) {
    list.add(DSL.when(conditions.get(i), (Field) fields.get(i)).otherwise(""));
}
customSelect.add(concat(list.toArray(new Field[0])).trim().as("fullAddress"));
```

Comment: Great answer! I will follow your last example as it's the cleanest of all, I already came up with nullity problem but I was trying to avoid concatenating the space every time by using concat_ws, seems it's not supported by JOOQ.

Comment: @MikelDalmau: You can always resort to using plain SQL, in order to add unsupported functionality to jOOQ: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql